# Compare two unix time stamps to see if they are on the same date in MySql

Tags: mysql

I have read various questions here on Stackoverflow about the use of FROM_UNIXTIME but none directly deal with what I am trying to do. I have one timestamp in a variable coming from php (that has been reformatted - e.g. 25 March 2014) to a function which uses a database query to determine if there are other entries in the database that have the same date (not time). I've run across various methods for formatting and comparing timestamp entries using MySql and ended up with the following but I understand that it isn't very efficient. Does anyone know of a better way to accomplish this?

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(sd.timestart, "%e %M %Y") = ?'
```

where the variable in my array for comparison is the date format listed above. This accomplishes what I want but, again, I don't think it is the most efficient way to get this done. Any advice and/or ideas will be much appreciated.

****EDIT****
My timestamp is stored as an integer so I'm trying to use:

```
$thissessiondate = strtotime($date->timestart, strtotime('today'));
```

and

```
$tomorrowdate = strtotime($date->timestart, strtotime('tomorrow'));
```

to do trim to midnight but get an error (strtotime() expects parameter 2 to be long) and when I move 'today' to the first argument position, I get a conversion to 11 pm instead of 0:00...? I'm making some progress but my very incomplete knowledge of both PHP and MySQL are holding me back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can avoid it, don't wrap columns used in predicates in expressions.

Have your predicates on bare columns to make index range scans possible.  You want the datatype conversion to happen over on the literal side of the predicate, wherever possible.

The STR_TO_DATE function is the most convenient for this.

Assuming the `timestart` column is DATE, DATETIME or TIMESTAMP (which it really should be, if it represents a point in time.)

```
WHERE sd.timestart >= STR_TO_DATE( ? , "%e %M %Y") 
  AND sd.timestart <  STR_TO_DATE( ? , "%e %M %Y") + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Effectively, what that's doing is taking the string passed in as the first argument to the STR_TO_DATE function, MySQL is going to convert that string to a DATETIME, based on the format specified as the second argument. And that effectively becomes a literal that MySQL can use to compare to the stored values in the column.

If there's an appropriate index available, MySQL will consider an index range scan operation to satisfy that predicate.

You'd need to pass in the same value twice, but that's not really a problem.

On the second line, we're just adding a day to the same value. So what MySQL is seeing is this:

```
WHERE sd.timestart >= STR_TO_DATE( '25 March 2014' , "%e %M %Y") 
  AND sd.timestart <  STR_TO_DATE( '25 March 2014' , "%e %M %Y") + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

In terms of performance, that's equivalent to:

```
WHERE sd.timestart >= '2014-03-15 00:00:00'
  AND sd.timestart <  '2014-03-16 00:00:00'
```

If you do it the other way around, and wrap timestart in a function, that's going to require MySQL to evaluate the function on every single row (or at least, on every row that isn't filtered out by another predicate first.)

**IMPORANT NOTE**

Be aware that MySQL interprets datetime values as being in the **timezone** of the MySQL connection, which defaults to the timezone setting of the MySQL server.  MySQL is going to interpret datetime literals in the current setting of the timezone. For example, if MySQL timezone is set to +00:00, then datetime literals will be interpreted as UTC.

---

I assumed the format string matches the data being passed in, I don't use %e or %m. The %Y is a four digit year. (The list of format elements is in the MySQL documentation, under the `DATE_FORMAT` function.

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

---

If your timestart column is INTEGER or other numeric datatype, representing a number of seconds or some other unit of time since the beginning of an era, you can use the same approach for performance benefits.

In the predicate, reference bare columns from the table, and do any conversions required on the literal side.

If you aren't using MySQL functions to do the conversion to "seconds since Jan 1, 1970 UTC" when rows are inserted (which is really what the TIMESTAMP datatype is doing internally), then I wouldn't recommend using MySQL functions to do the conversion in the query either.

If you're doing the conversion from date and time to an integer type "timestamp" in PHP, then I'd do the inverse conversion in PHP as well, and do the trimming to midnight and the adding of a day in PHP.

In that case, your MySQL query would be of the simple form:

```
  WHERE sd.timestart >= ? 
    AND sd.timestart <  ?
```

Where you would pass in the appropriate integer values, to compare to the INTEGER timestamp column.

---

Note that MySQL does provide a function for converting to "seconds since Jan 1 1970 UTC", so if timestart is seconds since Jan 1 1970 UTC, then something like this is valid:

```
WHERE sd.timestart >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE( '25 March 2014' , "%e %M %Y")) 
  AND sd.timestart <  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE( '25 March 2014' , "%e %M %Y") + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

**BUT...** again, be aware of timezone conversion issues; if the MySQL database has a different timezone setting than the web server. If you are going to store "integer", then I wouldn't muck that up with the conversion that MySQL does, which may not be exactly the same as the conversion functions the web server does.

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much for this detailed explanation! It took me a while but I now have my head around what you have explained here. My timestamp is stored in an integer :-( so now I'm trying to covert the raw timestamp from php (trim to midnight) but for some reason I'm not getting it to work. - Edited my post with new information because I couldn't fit it all in here.

Comment: @Jason Hollowell: I strongly recommend that if the datatype of the MySQL table column is **INTEGER**, and integer values are being inserted, then don't muck with MySQL datetime/timestamp conversions; you're going to want to use the same function library to do ALL of the conversions. Trying to mix that MySQL datetime/timestamp conversions and timezone issues is going to wind up being a mess. Just let MySQL deal with it as an integer. (The big reason for using INTEGER instead of DATETIME in the first place is to avoid problems caused by mixing datetime conversion functions.)

Comment: Thank you again for your help. Yes, they are in integers (big ones :-) e.g. - 1395824400). I just need to figure out how to trim them in php and then I'll be able to avoid the awkward and silly conversion back and forth in MySql. Either way though, thanks for the explanation...it made something I've been trying to figure out for several days so much easier to understand. (thumbs up)

Comment: @Jason Hollowell: maybe you can ask another question, not regarding MySQL at all, but just PHP, and ask how to "round down" and "round up" a unix timestamp value to the previous midnight or next midnight, in local timezone rather than UTC (or more generally, in any specified timezone that may or may not include daylight savings time adjustments, other than GMT.) It's possible that exact same question has already been asked on StackOverflow. Bottom line, I wouldn't push that conversion function down to the database, if the database functions weren't used to do the conversion in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

If you store your date as an int timestamp, you can do this

```
round(sd.timestart/86400)=round(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())/86400)
```

This will get everything in your database that is from the same day.

For example:

```
SELECT id FROM uploads WHERE (approved=0 OR approved is NULL) AND round(uploads.date/86400)<=round(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())/86400) order by uploads.date DESC LIMIT 20
```

Will display all the uploads for today and the days before, without showing the future uploads. 86400 is the number of seconds in one day.